PHP Preg Match Regex Skip Match, Only Take Group
hi I wanna skip matches in regex which I need group as the result
String
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNHW0MJL764&ab_channel=BeritaSatu

Regex
v=([A-z|0-9]+)

Well, the result is like this when dd
array:2 [▼ // app/View/Components/Widget/TabViewVideos.php:35
  0 => "v=3wFDAoIUpZQ"
  1 => "3wFDAoIUpZQ"
]

I just want to take this one "3wFDAoIUpZQ" as result

So access the element with index 1 then ...?

What about the combo parse_url/parse_str: https://3v4l.org/FABPX#v8.3.9

@CBroe Well, there are about 10 urls in a list. So, should I take the result [1],[3],[5]... Since [0],[2],[4] is for matches? I thought there are another way to do grouping
Like
[1] = [0] matches, [1] result
[2] = [0] matches, [1] result
....

Note that [A-z] matches more than just letters. Use [a-zA-Z0-9] or [[:alnum:]]. If you need something (-cool and) short: [^\W_]. I further guess you did not mean to include the pipe-character | into your character class.

@RadenBagus can you update the question with the code you're using, and an example string that demonstrates the problem

"If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
So as Cboe says:
preg_match(
   '/v=([A-z|0-9]+)/', 
   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNHW0MJL764&ab_channel=BeritaSatu', 
   $matches
);

$result = $matches[1];  // "SNHW0MJL764"


Thats what I did, but how to do 10 grouping? Should i take the result based on the key given? 1,3,5? I am talking about preg_match_all

@RadenBagus can you update the question with the code you're using, and an example string that demonstrates the problem
